# Meaning of て-form followed by さ

Tags: grammar

Hamaji is asked if his house ever recieves year-end gifts. He says that they get dried shiitake mushrooms. His friends express surprise. One of them says "it's not bad but..." and then Hamaji says:

> 「悪くはねぇんだよ。うちのかーちゃんなんてすげー喜んじゃってさぁ」
>   "It's **not** bad. Our mother ends up really happy" (my TL attempt)

I'm assuming 喜んじゃって is the て-form of 喜んじゃう which is a contraction of 喜んでしまう. I don't understand why it is in て-form or what the meaning of さぁ is. What is this てさぁ ending all about?

Comment: I'd just assume that the て form there means that the thought is left unfinished, that there are other reasons the speaker doesn't specify, probably because he can't recall them at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This -て and this さぁ are not strongly related, and we can discuss them separately.

Sentence-end -て is often used to [make a casual request](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12026/5010), and aside from that, it's used to make the sentence "unfinished", and keep the listener's attention.

- [Ending sentences with the て form](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28577/5010)

And さぁ/さあ/さ is yet another sentence-ending particle like ね(え), よ(お), わ.

So -てさぁ basically works as the attention drawer, like *you know*.

> It's not bad. My mom was actually really happy with that, *you know*.

Answer (score 3):

[て/で]さ[あ] doesn't really mean much, it just emphasizes the speaker's feeling was moved or the speaker was troubled in one way or another. "Trouble" might not be a good word here, as it can mean something overwhelmingly joyful has happened to the speaker.

> 聞いてよ〜 タカシの奴がひどくってさぁ〜
>   Listen to me [You know what?] [My boyfried] Takashi really annoys me!